# Disqus Iframe not resizing on AMP installation

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html, disqus, hugo

I'm trying to integrate Disqus on a Hugo theme I'm working on which uses AMP.

I've followed the recommended [installation guide](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-install-examples/tree/master/google-amp) so my `amp-iframe` has `allow-same-origin` value on the sandbox attribute and the `src` url is from a different domain.

My code for the iframe:

```
<amp-iframe width=600 height=180
    layout="responsive"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-popups allow-forms"
    resizable
    src="https://subdomain.asur.dev#code">

    <div overflow
        tabindex=0
        role=button
        aria-label="Load more"
        style="display:block;font-size:12px;font-weight:500;font-family:Helvetica Neue, arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;line-height:1.1;padding:12px 16px;border-radius:4px;background:rgba(29,47,58,0.6);color:rgb(255,255,255)">
        Load more
    </div>
</amp-iframe>
```

My embed code:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event)
{
    if (event.data) {
        var msg;
        try {
            msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        } catch (err) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        if (!msg)
            return false;

        if (msg.name === 'resize' || msg.name === 'rendered') {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                window.parent.postMessage({
                sentinel: 'amp',
                type: 'embed-size',
                height: msg.data.height
                }, '*');
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
<script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = window.location;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
        this.page.identifier = window.location.hash; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };
    (function() {
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
        s.src = 'https://shortname.disqus.com/embed.js';
        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
```

I'm not really sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong, but the `amp-example` on [iframe resizing](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-iframe/#resizable-iframe) works fine, so my browser is working.

Here, at the end of the page you can find an example of the iframe: https://asur.dev/en/amperage/theme-kitchen-sink/

Comment: how do you set up disqus for amp. I am having issues with iframe not showing fully (small size). also should i change `this.page.url = window.location; ` `this.page.identifier = window.location.hash;` or leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was making a redirect from a subdomain `subdomain.asur.dev` to a page in the main domain like `asur.dev/something`.

It looks like the initial AMP validation of the iframe passes and everything works fine, with no errors, but due to internal logic in the component the iframe is not able to resize.

The issue was solved when I moved the embed HTML to a completely independent subdomain with no redirects.

Comment: didn't get any validation errors? because you have used script tag directly here

Comment: @Urock The embeded page doesn't need to be a valid AMP page. That's exactly why I use iframe.

Comment: yes, i confused that embed-size request will be in AMP page but that request should be in embedded page, thank you, sometimes we do not control on embedded iframe to add this postMessage request, in that situation how we can handle this